# How to put input field into php echo tag?

Tags: php, input, echo

```
 <input name="order[]" type="text" class="pole" value="<? echo (($row['theorder']>0)&&($row['theorder']<1000))?$row['theorder']:"";?>" size="8">
```

I need to put this input field into php echo tag. How to do that? I know that I should place some slashes and dots, but have no idea where. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

Juste like this without any slashes or dots :

```
<input name="order[]" type="text" class="pole" value='
 <?php
 $row['theorder']=1;
 echo (($row['theorder']>0)&&($row['theorder']<1000))?$row['theorder']:"";
 ?>
'/>
```

Comment: This is parto of a table:
echo "<td><img class=\"miniatury\" src=\"../mthumb.php?pic=".$addP['file_name']."&w=80&sq=Y&b=Y\" align=absmiddle><br>
kolejność:&nbsp; 

< it should come here >
      
<br>główne:&nbsp;<input type=\"radio\" $selected name=\"main\" value=\"".$addP['id']."\"><br />usuń:&nbsp;<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"del_chk_addpic".$i."\" onClick=\"delete_pic(this.form,'addpic_".$i."');\"></td>";

It needs slashes before " etc. It doesn't work without it. I suppose this is piece of cake for a programmer but I am a graphics designer... So please, help.